# Wordpress compatible slider with HTML content in thumbnails

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, slider

I am just wondering if anybody knows of either a wordpress plugin or a stand alone slider that allows html content as thumbnails.

What I mean is that if you take a look here: http://tinyurl.com/pdfu3nn

The jockey on the horse would be the slider image and then the little boxes at the bottom of the image (1-4 with the text) would be the clickable thumbnails.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use for example [royal slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) which is a jquery plugin and there appears to be a wordpress plugin version also. Then you can simply use

```
$(".html_containing_divs").each(function(i){
  $(this).click(function(){
    $(".royalSlider").royalSlider('goTo', i);
  });
});
```

or something like that. Anyway I didn´t try Royal Slider yet, but it looks pretty good.
Also there is jquery Cycle plugin which also provides some goTo function: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/goto.html